# Loop XML nodes with grouping using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

With the following XML

```xml
<page>
  <chunk id="1001" sequence="1">
    <meta>Inline</meta>
    <body>Inline chunk 1</body>
  </chunk>
  <chunk id="1002" sequence="2">
    <meta>Tabs</meta>
    <body>Tab chunk 1</body>
  </chunk>
  <chunk id="1054" sequence="3">
    <meta>Tabs</meta>
    <body>Tab chunk 2</body>
  </chunk>
  <chunk id="1023" sequence="4">
    <meta>Inline</meta>
    <body>Inline chunk 2</body>
  </chunk>
  <chunk id="1013" sequence="5">
    <meta>Tabs</meta>
    <body>Tab chunk 3</body>
  </chunk>
  <chunk id="1072" sequence="6">
    <meta>Tabs</meta>
    <body>Tab chunk 4</body>
  </chunk>
</page>
```

I would like to apply an XSL template to output this:

```
<main>
  <section class="Inline>
    <div>Inline chunk 1</div>
  </section>
  <section class="Tabs>
    <div>Tab chunk 1</div>
    <div>Tab chunk 2</div>
  </section>
  <section class="Inline>
    <div>Inline chunk 2</div>
  </section>
  <section class="Tabs>
    <div>Tab chunk 3</div>
    <div>Tab chunk 4</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Basically I would like to output the `chunk` in the order of their `./@sequence`, but group them based on their `./meta` value when possible. By "possible", I mean only group them if they have the same `./meta` value and next to each other in sequence.

Using Muenchian Method, I could group the `chunk` by `./meta`, but only get the following result:

```
<main>
  <section class="Inline>
    <div>Inline chunk 1</div>
    <div>Inline chunk 2</div>
  </section>
  <section class="Tabs>
    <div>Tab chunk 1</div>
    <div>Tab chunk 2</div>
    <div>Tab chunk 3</div>
    <div>Tab chunk 4</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

This is the XSLT I use:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="kBucketByLabel" match="/page/chunk" use="./meta" />

  <!-- Then we override/define a template to match "/SAM" and write our body HTML here. -->
  <xsl:template match="/page" mode="body">
    <main>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="chunk[generate-id() = generate-id( key('kBucketByLabel', ./meta)[1] )]" mode="bucket">
        <xsl:sort select="@sequence" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </main>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chunk" mode="bucket">
    <xsl:variable name="bucket" select="./meta" />
    <section class="{$bucket}">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('kBucketByLabel', $bucket)">
        <div><xsl:value-of select="./body"/></div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </section>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: can you please append your XSLT too in your question

Comment: The output is not well-formed as it has multiple root elements.

Comment: can you use xsl 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is through a technique known as "sibling recursion":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/page">
    <main>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="chunk[not(meta = preceding-sibling::chunk[1]/meta)]"/>
    </main>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chunk">
    <section class="{meta}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="collect"/>
    </section>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chunk" mode="collect">
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="body"/>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::chunk[1][meta = current()/meta]" mode="collect"/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> Does this work with an unsorted chunks? In my sample data above, I
>   intentionally sorted them by `@sequence` for ease of visualization,
>   but my actual data are unsorted.
>   ...
>   I managed to have them sorted by
>   first looping through the `chunk`s with `<xsl:for-each>`, sort them by
>   `@sequence` and store copy of them to a RTF. I had to use extension to
>   convert the RTF into node-set and apply your technique. It works, but
>   I am hoping not to do that if possible.

Actually, that's exactly what I would do: sort the data first, convert it a node-set, then apply the above method in a second pass.

If you don't want to that, you could use a **key** to refer to the previous/next chunk in sequence - provided that the sequence is contiguous:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="chunk" match="chunk" use="@sequence" />

<xsl:template match="/page">
    <main>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="chunk[not(meta = key('chunk', @sequence - 1)/meta)]">
            <xsl:sort select="@sequence" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </main>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chunk">
    <section class="{meta}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="collect"/>
    </section>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chunk" mode="collect">
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="body"/>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('chunk', @sequence + 1)[meta = current()/meta]" mode="collect"/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does this work with an unsorted chunks? In my sample data above, I intentionally sorted them by `@sequence` for ease of visualization, but my actual data are unsorted. From what I understand, using `preceding-sibling` will only work with the current order of nodes.

Comment: I managed to have them sorted by first looping through the `chunk`s with `<xsl:for-each>`, sort them by `@sequence` and store copy of them to a RTF. I had to use extension to convert the RTF into node-set and apply your technique. It works, but I am hoping not to do that if possible.

Comment: @sntran After you sort the chunks by sequence, will they form a contiguous series? IOW, if a chunk has sequence = 4, can one assume that the preceding chunk, after sorting, will have sequence = 3 (or some other value computable from 4)?

Comment: They will be contiguous series after sorted, i.e. they will look exactly like my posted sample data.

Comment: See the addtiion to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Both ways work. I would upvote you more if I could.

Just out of curiosity, if it was you, which way would you go? The first way seems to take up memory due to all the copying, but using key on each `@sequence` seems to create N indexes. I'm not sure which one would perform better in a relative large number of `chunk` nodes.

Comment: If it's about performance, I would test with the actual processor to be used in production.

Comment: sorry to bring back this question, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get all the `chunk`s  with the same `/meta` within the template rule that mach "chunk" with no "mode". Essentially, I would like NOT to apply another template (mode "collect" in this case).